# Python :invalid print error

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm getting error while printing `y`. Can someone please expain why?

```
from math import *

def polysum(n, s):
    x = 0.25 * n * (s**2)
    print (x)
    y = (math.tan(math.pi / n)
    print (y)
    z = x / y

    return  z

x = polysum(5, 57)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the previous line. You have an extra opening parenthesis in `y=(math.tan(math.pi/n)` (or are missing a closing parenthesis). Also, your math import was broken, you can either use `from math import *` and then call `tan` directly, or `import math` and then `math.tan`.

Here is a fixed version removing the unnecessary open paren and fixing the import.

```
import math

def polysum(n, s):
    x = 0.25 * n * (s**2)
    print (x)
    y = math.tan(math.pi / n)
    print (y)
    z=x / y

    return z

x=polysum(5, 57)
print (x)
```